# Can't find the solution to this exception: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: name expected (position:START_TAG <null>@

Tags: java, android

I'm tying to parse .gpx file and recieve exception:
    09-01 21:00:16.603: W/System.err(11762): org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: name expected       (position:START_TAG @136:28 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41887c50)

Here is my .gpx file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <gpx><wpt>
                    <id>23512</id>
                    <lat>45.351486</lat>
                    <lon>36.474290</lon>
                    <name>Картинная галерея. г. Керчь</name>
                   </wpt><wpt>
                    <id>23512</id>
                    <lat>45.351486</lat>
                    <lon>36.474290</lon>
                    <name>Картинная галерея. г. Керчь</name>
                   </wpt><wpt>
                    <id>23436</id>
                    <lat>48.943566</lat>
                    <lon>34.185650</lon>
                    <name>Ветряк</name>
                   </wpt><wpt>
                    <id>23436</id>
                    <lat>48.943566</lat>
                    <lon>34.185650</lon>
                    <name>Ветряк</name>
                   </wpt>....
```

Here is my code:
onCreate:

```
List<Location> gpxList = null;
File gpxFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Shukach/shukach.gpx");

    gpxList = decodeGPX(gpxFile);
```

method:

```
private List<Location> decodeGPX(File file) {
List<Location> list = new ArrayList<Location>();

DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
        .newInstance();
try {
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory
            .newDocumentBuilder();
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(fileInputStream);
    Element elementRoot = document.getDocumentElement();

    NodeList nodelist_wpt = elementRoot.getElementsByTagName("wpt");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodelist_wpt.getLength(); i++) {

        Node node = nodelist_wpt.item(i);
        NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();

        String newLatitude = attributes.getNamedItem("lat")
                .getTextContent();
        Double newLatitude_double =   Double.parseDouble(newLatitude);

        String newLongitude = attributes.getNamedItem("lon")
                .getTextContent();
        Double newLongitude_double =     Double.parseDouble(newLongitude);

        String newLocationName = newLatitude + ":" + newLongitude;
        Location newLocation = new Location(newLocationName);
        newLocation.setLatitude(newLatitude_double);
        newLocation.setLongitude(newLongitude_double);

        list.add(newLocation);
        Log.d(TAG, newLocationName);
    }

    fileInputStream.close();

} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return list;
```

}

I can't understand the problem and can't find solution on internet... Plz help.

Comment: You seem to be expecting `lat` and `lon` to be attributes of the `wpt` node, but in the sample XML, they are child elements, so your code may be incorrect.

Comment: Can you show us line 136 of the .gpx file?

Comment: line 136: <name>< Бурты ---- Буэнос-Айрес ></name>